# Is it possible to have a Dojo widget that appears as an un-styled HTML control?

Tags: dojo

Is it possible to have a Dojo widget that appears as an un-styled HTML control, but still provides the additional functionality?

For example the `dijit.form.Select` widget normally appears like this:

[image: DIJIT Select]

Is there a way to get it to look like the browser default select?

Answer (score 1):

1. Your picture looks [way off](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/form/Select.html). Are you sure you included the stylesheet for your theme and added the appropriate class name to the body tag?
2. If you want domething that looks like a default select, why not just use a default select? You didn't mention any widget-specific functionality that you need
3. You can always create your own widgets with your own custom HTML and CSS structure if you really need to.

Comment: `.addOption`, `.options = [ ]`.  Raw DOM selects are just hard to deal with, and DOJO doesn't seem to provide any convenience methods for them, unless you're using their widgets.

Comment: Dojo has DOM manipulation so you can easily add options with dojo.create('option', {innerHTML: 'value'}, selectNode); Anyway the default dijit widget should look fine if you include the css correctly (instead of showing the down-arrow HTML synmbol thingy)